# Connecting L3 and L2 switches with VLAN settings

Tags: routing, vlan, ip, ethernet, networking

I have 1 L3 switch with
Static ip - 192.168.0.252

Two L2 switches
Switch A - 192.168.0.250
Switch B - 192.168.0.251

I have created VLANs in L3 switches with 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.2.2 ips abd set it in router mode

Devices that will be connected to switch A will be in the 192.168.1.x range and in the switch B will be 192.168.2.x

I am not able to find the right modes Access/Hybrid/Trunk to actually implement this setting with problem VLAN id's

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to include a diagram or a good description of how they are connected, the switch models, and the switch configurations that you have now. Given more-specific information, we can give more-specific answers.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to connect devices on both L2 switches to either VLAN then you need to trunk those VLANs (on both the L3 and the L2 switch). Since you seem to be using a management subnet 192.168.0.0/24 you most likely need VLAN trunks.

Alternatively, you could use access-mode ports to the switches, treating them like unmanaged ones. Management access would require a dedicated link.

Hybrid mode requires additional setup to differentiate VLANs e.g. by L3 protocol - I can't think of any scenario where that is useful.

Ports for end nodes should generally be in access mode. An exception may be servers and especially hypervisors that are VLAN aware themselves.

Answer (score 0):

His answer simplified:

Your uplink Interface on each switch needs to be in trunk mode, allowing the specific vlans through the trunk or simply allow all vlans through the trunk ports going to each switch.

On switch A, you can set the local interfaces going to the endpoint as access ports and set their vlan access to the vlan to 1.1, likewise do the same on switch B.

This will allow both switches to receive all vlans from their uplink (Make sure the uplink also has a trunk port configured on the other side, allowing the said vlans). And then assign the desired vlan to a specific LAN port.

If using an AP where you want to create different SSID's to different VLANS, just set the port going to the AP to Trunk and set VLANS in the SSID settings within the AP.